# Crashing WCF WebService on Windows Phone

Tags: web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, endpoint

I am using 3 webservices in my project and it was running correctly. But in these days it is crashing when creating it's client and **I haven't changed anything**.

[image]

[image]

How can I solve it, could you help me, please?

Comment: Not sure it has anything to do with the issue, but I can't help but notice that your configuration file is missing the XML header: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Try updating the service reference, or deleting it and adding it again.

Comment: I have done but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying your service config file is not found. Are you referencing it correctly from the app.config?

It looks like you're using WPF or Silverlight so find your app.config file.

You cannot apply configSource= to  since that is a config section group - not a simple config section, and the configSource attribute is only available on simple configuration sections.

You should however absolutely be able to apply the configSource attribute to any of the nodes inside  - I do this all the time, in production systems - and it just works; for behaviors, services, clients, bindings, etc; each in a separate .config file.

.ClientConfig is also a bad extension. All configuration files should have .config extension.

In the worst case scenario that you can't configure the external config source for the settings, move them back tot he app.config file of the application!

Comment: could you explain me how I can do it? Because in the past, Visual Studio was doing it itself.